# Website builders (Like wix/squarespace) don't seem to offer database's/MySql. But my software has to check to see if user paid

Tags: mysql, database, squarespace, weebly

Hello fellow stack overflowlings, I had what some might consider a basic question. I want to make a software program that has to verify if a user has paid for the program before letting them use it. (I.E A login screen) but in order to do this I need a website that has a MySql database, but all the website building companies (Like Square space/ Weebly/ Wix) Don't seem to offer any type of database integration. I was wondering if anyone knows if its possible to connect these types of websites to a MySql database or If I just have to code the whole website on my own. Thanks! (Sorry English is not my primary language.)

Comment: Wix/Weebly/SquareSpace are not really appropriate for this. Host somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure Wix will be out of the scope of what you need to do, but I've paired http://firebase.com up to a Squarespace site with great results. Firebase is not MySql though.

I would look to other platforms instead of Squarespace and Wix.

Comment: I've been looking for other platforms where I could get Squarespace-ian templates, _without_ their hosting plans. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

If database is not possible with Wix and other platforms, i would suggest you use **WordPress** for the site. WordPress is free, though you will have to get a hosting company to host it for you. Almost all hosting companies support WordPress. You can use it to create almost any site and it support database.

It also has thousands of plugins that you can get free on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Some webapp builders allow you to fetch data from an external database, such as AppWrite, ToolJet, or AppSmith. These are more webapp builders then website builders, and allow you to hook custom logic to your site.

Another lightweight solution is [SQLPage](https://sql.ophir.dev), to build a web UI for a database entirely in SQL, and it supports MySQL.